# How can I animate my mouse for screencasts?

Tags: mouse, screencast

I need to create some screencast tutorials, and I would like to animate my mouse for this purpose. E.g. Ideally I would like my mouse to be highlighted, to use an animation when clicking, and possibly to show click and drags. Can anyone suggest a solution?

I am happy using gtk-record-my-destop for the screencasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using compiz (part of Ubuntu's Unity DE) you can install [ccsm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) and there is a mouse option that adds spinning objects around the mouse, you can reduce there spacing to 0 or near it so it will be right on the mouse, if you need to record the keyboard presses/mouse buttons you can use [keymon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/) (the debs do not install the program, just dependencies); also i think [kazam](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kazam) works better than [gtk-record-my-desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk-record-my-desktop)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, GM-Script-Writer-62580, key-mon is very helpful. Thank you very much for that. I do have ccsm installed, but the advanced search doesn't pull up any mouse options like you describe. Where might I find that?

I have tried kazam, and it is nice too. Both kazam and gtk-record-my-desktop work fine for me.

Comment: try installing [compiz-plugins](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compiz-plugins)

Comment: older versions of ubuntu use [compiz-plugins-extra](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compiz-plugins-extra)

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification GM, the ccsm mouse settings do suit my needs.