# How do I highlight my mouse pointer while screen recording?

Tags: 16.04, cursor, screencast, mouse-pointer

I'm planning to record some tutorial videos. How do I make a mouse pointer/cursor with yellow circle around it on Ubuntu 16.04, so my students could see where I am?

Comment: [Older similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293707/how-can-i-animate-my-mouse-for-screencasts).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yellow circle can be done by installing any one of the following software:

1. [Cam studio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/): Is an open source windows software. Install it using wine then go to cursor settings. There is a cursor highlight.
2. RealWorld Cursor Editor: Also for Windows. Using this, you can directly edit your mouse properties.
3. [vokoscreen](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/vokoscreen): To install `sudo apt-get install vokoscreen`
4. [cairo-dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/) there is a add on to highlight the mouse pointer.
5. Use [gnome-tweak-tool](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/gnome-tweak-tool).

Comment: Nothing for Teamviewer?

Comment: vokoscreen is now vokoscreen.ng https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreenNG

Answer (score 39):

There is no large, colored, or animated mouse cursor by default.

To show the mouse position there is a gsetting key to allow showing the cursor position with orange circles upon pressing and releasing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

[image: ![enter image description here]

The key is located in `org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer` accessible through [**dconf-editor**](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/dconf-editor) as shown above or in a terminal with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true
```

Comment: It may be helpful to know `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer true` appears to be persistent across reboots and you don't need to add it to `/etc/rc.local` or any other startup areas.

Comment: It does not work very well. If you use nautilus to rename a file (f2) and then try to copy the file using control+c then the 'locate-pointer' func interfer and you cannot copy the file name into the clipboard (16.04 LTS). I had to disable it.

Comment: It works fine, but it requires pressing Ctrl each time. I'd like to configure it like: enable it when I press some keys + disable it when I press some keys. Sometimes I want it to be there for more seconds / minutes.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer: this most likely is hardcoded and can't be changed.

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer on my 4K screen with two other screens this isn't as good for me as it used to be. I was thinking of changing code to five to ten times bigger with black and white colors instead of washed out orange. You could try searching for the source code too.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 I had to use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface locate-pointer true` ... apparently the setting got moved around or so?!

Comment: @0xC0000022L well spotted, thank you very much. It indeed moved around a bit. Tested and works in 21.04  too.

Answer (score 25):

### Highlight Pointer Using Cursor Themes

I recently wanted to do this as well. I ended up at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269538) which had some broken links and left me still in search of themes that someone else had surely created. I found one I liked. Here's an animated GIF of what I ended up with and how I got it working.

**The end result**
[image: image.gif]

**Finding a cursor theme**

When I realized that this could be accomplished with a cursor theme (duh!), I went in search of some themes. I eventually ended up [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/107/ord/latest/), and after looking through a number of pages of different cursors, I settled on [this one](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/999801/). To download, click the files tab and then download the .tar.gz file for the cursor theme.

**Installing and enabling the cursor for screencasting**

With the cursor theme downloaded, I got to work on installing it.

- The file I downloaded contains multiple themes (each a different color halo) so I first extracted the contents to a temp folder

  ```
  tar -xzf /path/to/download/160115-bDMZT.tar.gz -C /tmp/
  ```
- Then I copied the cyan theme to the proper directory, renaming it `screencast`

  ```
  sudo cp -r /tmp/bDMZT/abDMZ/ /usr/share/icons/screencast/
  ```
- Before enabling the new cursor theme, I made note of the current theme.

  ```
  OLD_THEME=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme) && echo $OLD_THEME
  ```
- At this point, all that was left to do was to enable the theme.

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme screencast
  ```

If the new theme is active for some applications but not others or if it does not appear to be active at all, you may need to completely terminate all instances of the applications for which it is not active or log off entirely and log back in.

**Changing back to the default cursor**

Once you're finished your screencast, you may want to switch back to your previous theme (the system default is `DMZ-White`). To do this, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "$OLD_THEME"
```

---

**Extra 2-cents**

There are also programs available to [show mouse clicks and key presses](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/10/show-keyboard-and-mouse-key-presses-and.html) which can be really helpful in screencasts.

Comment: To the future explorers: key-mon (from the link in the "Extra 2-conts" is all you need! :) (you can add a circle to the mouse pointer in the settings)

Comment: thanks,but it change back to original theme when moved on chrome browser,any fix?

Comment: @JobayerShajal, you ran into the issue I described where all instances of the application for which it does not appear to be working need to be terminated. Close *all* instances of Chrome and reopen Chrome, and you should see the current theme in Chrome as well.

Comment: xie xie,@b_lasohi

Comment: @b_laoshi I quit all chrome tab and instances,then reopen. still the mouse return back to default Yaru theme on chrome.Logged out and logged in back,still same issue

Comment: @JobayerShajal, I've not tried this solution with snaps. Is your Chrome installation a snap by chance?

Comment: yes,you are right

Answer (score 6):

I have not tested this, but I think it's the right answer.

- Open compiz config: `sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager && ccsm`
- Look for plugin Show mouse, under Accessibility - ENABLE it..
- Play with it, to see if that's okay :)

You'll need `compiz-plugins` package to have this option.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The "Show mouse" plugin has no effect for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3.18.

Comment: Couldn't find "Show mouse" plugin on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.2 after installing compiz-config-settings-manager. There is only "Mouse poll interval" setting under accessibility options.

Comment: if you need to install `compiz-plugins` for Ubuntu12 and above:
`sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`